# Does the term "G-d" (i.e Elokim) include the concept of ruler?

Tags: words, theology

Often times Hashem is referred to as *Elokim* or *Elokecha* and the like, (10 commandments etc.) does this term include the terms/concepts of *manhig* or *reshuiot*?

In other words, could someone theoretically have 1 *Elokim* while still believing in multiple "rulers"

Comment: Note however the first commandment.

Comment: Obviously people can have multiple rulers. Everyone in Czarist Russia was ruled by the Czar, for instance. In what way is this question not just a semantic game?

Comment: baruch shekivanti http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28106501#28106501

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps I should delete the last line? My question is regarding the nature of what a "G-d" would constitute. Is it merely an object or worship, or does it presuppose omnipotence etc. G-d being the translation of the hebrew "Elokim"

Comment: Note that it is also used in the torah for *judges* or *rulers* in the secular sense.

Comment: There is One ruler with proper atribute and there are multiple rulers un which this atribute is not proper

Answer (score 0):

The term in Hebrew implies *powers* as we see in [B'reishis 6:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8171#showrashi=true) It applies to both secular and sacred. When used in the sacred sense, it means Hashem (singular as with *Royal We*). When used in the secular sense it means those with powers as with nobles, princes, judges, etc. See the reference to Moshe and Aharon in [Shmos 4:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9865#v=16&showrashi=true)

**B'Reishis**

> 2 That the sons of the nobles saw the daughters of man when they were
>   beautifying themselves, and they took for themselves wives from
>   whomever they chose.

**Rashi**

> **the sons of the nobles**: Heb. בְּנֵי הָאֱלֹהִים, the sons of the princes (Targumim) and the judges (Gen. Rabbah 26:5). Another
>   explanation: בְּנֵי הָאֱלֹהִים are the princes who go as messengers of
>   the Omnipresent. They too mingled with them (Pirkei d’Rabbi Eliezer,
>   ch. 22). Every אֱלֹהִים in Scripture is an expression of authority,
>   and the following proves it (Exod. 4:16): “And you shall be to him as
>   a lord (לֵאלֹהִים)”; (ibid. 7:1): “See, I have made you a lord
>   (אֶלֹהִים).”
>
> **when they were beautifying themselves**: Heb., טֹבֹת. Said Rabbi Judan: It is written טבת [i.e., instead of טובות. Thus it can be read
>   טָבַת, meaning to beautify.] When they would beautify her, adorned to
>   enter the nuptial canopy, a noble would enter and have relations with
>   her first (Gen. Rabbah 26:5).
>
> **from whomever they chose:** Even a married woman, even males and animals (Gen. Rabbah ad loc.).

**Shmos**

> 16 And he will speak for you to the people, and it will be that he
>   will be your speaker, and you will be his leader.

**Rashi**

> leader: Heb. לֵאלֹהִים, as a master and as a prince.